# UML tool which generates a document and php code automatically

Tags: php, uml, class-diagram, staruml, plantuml

I am looking for a UML tool with the following features:

1. Draw diagrams(sequence, class, use case, system architecture, database) by entering some text format or from the code structure.
2. From the diagram, I should be able to generate a word document with class names, function names, input and output parameters in a suitable format.
3. From the diagram, I should be able to generate code (classes) in PHP automatically.

Please suggest such tools.

Comment: See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Architect_(software)

Comment: I concur with @xmojmr, take a look at Enterprise Architect, Desktop or Professional Edition by Sparx Systems. While it is not free, it is well worth its price ($135 - $199), It will take some time to master, but it is time invested well. It will be *the* tool for any UML-based design for application, database, process, and other designs.

Comment: yeah. I have analysed Enterprise Architect with trial version and its good in most of the cases. But I don't see it generating the document out of class diagram. Any suggestions?